# How to get url from browser intent

Tags: android

I'm trying to authenticate a user from a website. When the user clicks approve or deny, the app will get the url from which it's redirected and check if it contains `approve=true` or `deny=true`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebView you can intercept url like this :

```
 myWebView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient()
    {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished( WebView view, String url )
      {
      // check if there is approve in url
      }
    }
```